# Passing position and color of square to UIView subview

Tags: iphone, ios4, parameter-passing, draw

I work on a project for iPhone iOS4 with Xcode.

From MainViewController I want to draw a little red square (fill only, not stroke) in MyView, a subclass of UIView. How can I pass position and RGB color of the square?

MyView.h (subclass of UIView)

```
 @interface {
 CGPoint position; // OK
 CGFloat[3] color; // ???
 }
 @property CGPoint position; // OK
 @property CGFloat color;    // ???
```

MyView.m

```
 @synthesize position; // OK
 @synthesize color;    // ???
```

MainViewController.h

```
 MyView *myRect;
 property IBOutlet MyView *myRect;
```

MainViewController.m

```
 @synthesize myRect;

 - (void) viewDidLoad
    myRect.position = CGPointMake (0, 0); // OK
    myRect.color = CGFloat [] = {255, 0, 0, 1}  // ???
```

I think I have no problems with the position of the square. But how can I pass the color of the square?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[myRect setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:color[0] green:color[1] blue:color[2] alpha:1.0]];
```

Comment: myRect is the view in which I want to draw a little red square. I want to pass position and color of the square in myRect.

Comment: ok. I misunderstood your question entirely .. Why not just pass a UIColor object ? UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0 should do the trick for you. Just have to redefine color to be of type UIColor *